# Iterate over one collection and get the same index value of another collection

Tags: java, stream, modelmapper

I want know is it even possible in Java to iterate over, let say a list, and get/set the same index(int) value of other list?

```
for (Response e : responseList) {         
   e.setPrimarySkills(requestList.get(??).getPrimarySkills());
}
```

Since it can't be done through model mapper because of the issues, is there any neat way of doing the same ?

Comment: Don't do it with a for-each loop, use an indexed for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two iterators:

```
Iterator<Response> responseIt = responseList.iterator();
Iterator<Request> requestIt = requestList.iterator();
while(responseIt.hasNext() && requestIt.hasNext()) {
  Response response = responseIt.next();
  Request request = requestIt.next();
  ...
}
```

---

[Recommended for its clarity]

Using Guava [Streams.forEachPair](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#forEachPair-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) :

```
Streams.forEachPair(
  requestList.stream(), 
  responseList.stream(), 
  (req, resp) -> resp.setPrimarySkills(req.getPrimarySkills())
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either, don't do it with a for-each loop, use an indexed for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < responseList.size(); ++i) {
  responseList.get(i).setPrimarySkills(requestList.get(i).getPrimarySkills());
}
```

Or, use a pair of `Iterator`s:

```
Iterator<Response> responseIt = responseList.iterator();
Iterator<Request> requestIt = requestList.iterator();

while (responseIt.hasNext() && requestIt.hasNext()) {
  // Put responseIt.next() and requestIt.next() into variables, if you want.  
responseIt.next().setPrimarySkills(requestIt.next().getPrimarySkills());
}
```

The advantage of `Iterator`s over an index is that `Iterator`s are efficient for non-`RandomAccess` lists; but, unless your lists are big, it's unlikely to be a significant (or even noticable) difference.

---

You can do it with a for-each loop, by maintaining the index yourself, but it's a bit inconsistent in the treatment of the two lists:

```
int i = 0;
for (Response e : responseList) {         
   e.setPrimarySkills(requestList.get(i).getPrimarySkills());
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-loop with incrementing index:

```java
List<String> l1 = List.of("a", "b");
List<Integer> l2 = List.of(1, 2);

for(int i=0; i<l1.size(); i++) {
  String s = l1.get(i);
  Integer i = l2.get(i);
}
```

Of course you should first make sure that both lists have equal length, to avoid OutOfBounds Exception.

Comment: You could also do `i<l1.size() || i<l2.size();` for the loop condition to ensure `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` cannot be thrown since it will only ever iterate to the length of the smaller `List` as an option.

Comment: @Nexevis Sure you can. Depends on what you're trying to achieve. Throwing an Exception could also be fine, or don't run the loop at all when list sizes don't match.

Comment: Yeah of course, not saying it is a _better_ option, just was giving as an option for OP incase it fits his criteria.

Comment: @Nexevis I took it as a given that the request list's size is at least the size of the response list, as this seemed implicit in the question.